# search database by date

Tags: java, mysql, swing, datetime

I want to search column called `name` in my `work` table by searching date. Other columns are `id(primary key) and mydate`. I can't find what is wrong with my code. I'm using jdbc class for db connection.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)             {                                         
   String date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
    String time1 = dateSpinner1.getValue().toString().split(" ")[3];
    date1 = date1 + " " + time1;

    try {
        ResultSet rs =db.getData("SELECT * FROM work WHERE mydate = '"+date1+"'");
      while (rs.next()) {                
           String name = rs.getString("name");
         System.out.println(name);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? printStackTrace() ??

Comment: problem is that. there is no error output. :( is there anyway that I can out put the error..

Comment: I changed cord as          if (rs.first()) {                
                jTextField2.setText(rs.getString("name"));
            } else {
           System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
         }                                                        so I'm having : java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is the name of a function in MySQL. You'll need to wrap it in ` characters:

```
ResultSet rs =db.getData("SELECT * FROM work WHERE `date` = '"+date1+"'");
```

Comment: You need not quote 'date', sql will consider it as coumn name='date' and not as date.

Comment: changed  ResultSet rs =db.getData("SELECT * FROM work WHERE mydate = '"+date1+"'"); mydate is table column name. Still not working..

Comment: My bad, then, I've had that problem before but apparently it must be something else. Hope you find it!

Answer (score 0):

One possible error may be that in database hours minutes and seconds are not 0:0:0 and from datechooser you are getting these fields as 0 : 0

Comment: my datechooser format is  yyyy MM dd . and datespinner format is hh:mm:ss a .

Comment: print output of date1 = date1 + " " + time1; and visually compare with value in the table. are they same?

Answer (score 0):

Could you pass the date1 as date in the statement (as parameter)?

```
"SELECT * FROM work WHERE date = ?" and pass parameter as date
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question